# Is there a way to scale this program to process multiple lines of JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas, file-upload

I am trying to write a code that takes an input as multiple nested JSON objects (every object is on a new line) -

```
{JSONObject1}
{JSONObject2}
.
.
{JSONObjectn}
```

from a text file and eventually flatten and convert them into a CSV file. The program that I have referenced from - https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

is currently converting one such line of nested JSON object from the text file and writing it to the csv file.

How can I scale this code to work with "n" such JSON data objects, all on separate lines in the text file?

Here is my current code -

```
import pandas as pd
import json

f = open('input.txt', )
data = json.load(f)


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = flatten_json(data)
df = pd.json_normalize(flat)
export_csv = df.to_csv(r'output.csv')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess loop through the file is all you need? Then just do:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
dfs = []
for line in f:
    data = json.loads(line)
    flat = flatten_json(data)
    df = pd.json_normalize(flat)
    dfs.append(df)
export_csv = pd.concat(dfs).to_csv('output.csv')
```

Of course if you don't care about the order of the data, you can also use multi-thread to speed it up but I think that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code and the error am getting is -

return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

even tried changing 

json.load(line)  to json.loads(line.read()) but no use.


Any suggestions on how to solve this error?

Comment: Typo. it's actually `json.loads(line)` instead of `json.load(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ethan ! With the help of your code, I came up with an updated version of the code which works smoothly! I know you mentioned multithreading and that's something I am exploring now, as a next step. Currently, this code below takes around 1min for processing 150 sets of data which includes

- reading from the file
- making a get request to the API
- flatten the nested JSON response and
- then write it all at once to a CSV file).

Any suggestions around how we can process thousands of line of data without it taking hours to run?

Updated Code -

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


data = []

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for id in f_input:
        url = "API_url"
        PARAMS = {'param1': id.strip()}
        resp = requests.get(url, headers={
            'headerkey': 'headervalue'}, params=PARAMS)
        flat = flatten_json(resp.json())
        df = pd.json_normalize(flat)
        data.append(df)

export_csv = pd.concat(data).to_csv(r'output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example of how you can achieve it. Basically it will create 4 processes, and each process will grab 4 lines at a time to convert it to json.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out


def parse_line(line):
    data = json.loads(line)
    flat = flatten_json(data)
    return pd.json_normalize(flat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
        dfs = pool.map(parse_line, f, 4)
        pool.close()
        pd.concat(dfs).to_csv('output.csv')
```